# Перерисовка стандартных компонентов формы в C++ Builder

Tags: c++

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке. Каким образом можно, если вообще возможно, перерисовать компоненты (сама форма, кнопки и т.п.)?

Comment: [Invalidate](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TControl_Invalidate.html)